# Using Html2canvas in Angular takes transparent screenshots ignoring the background?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, makefile, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of the specific div and then send that file in the Api
the div is basically a check book design .The user fills the input field and the check design is selected dynamically . Now the Html2Canvas works fine it takes the screenshot of the all the input fields but the only problem i face is that it does not capture the background image.
here are the error it shows.
[image]

```
            here is the html code 

          <div class="" id="check">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-10 text-center">
                <div class=" check mt-3"
                  [style]="'background-image: url(' + selectedCheckFrontBG + '); max-width:               
                   1200px'">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row pt-2 pb-2 first-row px-md-4">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-5 payer-logo text-left">
                        <div *ngIf="slides && slides.length > 0">
                          <div *ngFor="let slide of slides">
                            <div class="mr-lg-5" contentEditable="true" [(ngModel)]="pincode">
                              {{slide.preferred_name_on_check}}</div>
                            <p class="m-0" contentEditable="true">{{slide.address_on_check}}
                            </p>
                          </div>


                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-5  col-2 text-right">
                      </div>



                      <div class="col-md-3 col-5 text-right">
                        <div *ngIf="slides && slides.length > 0">
                          <div *ngFor="let slide of slides">
                            <h5 class="mr-lg-5" contentEditable="true" [(ngModel)]="pincode">
                              {{slide.bank_routing_number}}</h5>

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="date">
                          <input type="date" class="pay-data" [(ngModel)]="Date">
                        </div>
                      </div>



                    </div>
                    <div class="second-row pt-2 pb-1 px-md-2">
                      <div class="first-column">
                        <h6>PAY TO THE ORDER OF</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="second-column">
                        <input type="text" id="pay" name="pay" class="pay-data"
                          style="border-right: 1px solid black; height:   calc(1em + .75rem + 
                         2px);"
                          [(ngModel)]="payToOrder">
                      </div>
                      <div class="fourth-column ml-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
                          </div>
                          <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" class="form-control"
                            style="height: calc(1em + .75rem + 2px); outline: none"
                            (keyup)="convertAmountToWords($event)" 
                           (change)="convertAmountToWords($event)"
                            step="0.01" [(ngModel)]="amount">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row py-md-1 px-md-3">
                      <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <!-- <input type="text" name="numberInString" 
                     [(ngModel)]="numberInStrings" id="numberInString"
                          class="pay-data" > -->
                        <div class="pay-data">{{numberInstring}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pb-md-2 dollars px-md-3">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-5 bank-logo">
                        <p class="m-0 p-0" style="font-size: 12px">Affinity Federal Credit 
                    Union</p>
                        <p class="m-0 p-0" style="font-size: 12px">425 Any st.
                          Any city, US 45202</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-4 text-right">
                        <h6>(Void After 90 Days)</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-3 text-right ">
                        <h4>DOLLARS &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-lock"></i></h4>

                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="third-row px-md-2">
                      <div class="first-column text-center">
                        <h6 class="pt-3">MEMO</h6>
                        <div> <input type="text" id="memo" name="memo" class="pay-data" 
                     [(ngModel)]="memo"></div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="second-column">

                      </div>
                      <div class="third-column">
                        <h6 class="pt-3">Signature</h6>
                        <input type="text" id="Signature" name="Signature" class="pay-data">
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col text-center ch-number badge check-number text-dark ">


                        <div *ngIf="slides && slides.length > 0">
                          <div *ngFor="let slide of slides">
                            <span>C</span>
                            <span>{{slide.bank_routing_number}}</span>
                            <span>C</span>
                            <span style="padding-left: 5px;">{{slide.current_check_number}}
                        </span>
                            <span>A</span>
                            <span style="padding-left: 5px;">{{slide.bank_account_number}}
                       </span>
                            <span>C</span>
                            <span>000</span>
                            <span>d</span>
                          </div>


                        </div>
                        <!-- c1001c a221283512a &nbsp; &nbsp; 56502052c -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and here is the typescript code

```
  postData(imageFile ? : File, body ? : any, ) {
   const url = 'https://staging.pay2mate.com/api/bank/create-echeck/';
   const token = 'P2MToken 6ae2835d1351d4e71bb841e3888ae89f78d35925c9db26d932c47f11a298e067';

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('front_image', imageFile, imageFile.name);

   const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: token
   });



  Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, body[key]);
  });

  this.http.post(url, formData, {
      headers
    })
   .subscribe(
      response => {
       console.log('Response:', response);
       // Handle the response as needed
      },
     error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
       // Handle the error as needed
      }
    );
 }

 captureScreenshot() {
    console.log('Selected Id:', this.selectedId);
    const element = document.getElementById('check');

 html2canvas(element, {
     useCORS: true
    })
  .then((canvas) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/png');
    });
    })
   .then((blob: Blob) => {
     const file = new File([blob], 'screenshot.png', {
       type: 'image/png'
     }); // Create File object
     console.log(file);

    this.body = {
      echeck_issued_amount: this.amount,
      issuer_bank_account: this.selectedId,
      echeck_issued_ts: this.Date,
      beneficiary_name: this.payToOrder,
      barcode_number: 'barcode_number',
      echeck_pin_code: this.pincode,
      digital_instrument_type: 'ECHECK',
      receiver_bank_account: '',
      notify_payee: this.isChecked,
      email: this.email
    };

    this.postData(file, this.body);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error capturing screenshot:', error);
  });
   }
```

i am want the screenshot with the background but it is taking transparent screenshots.